# UNITY3D How to do multiple animations on the same object at the same time?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, synchronization, state-machine

Unity version: 5.6.2f1

[Tech ring image](https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/183383/tech-rings.png)

I have a tech ring separated into multiple parts (image is down below). I've animated the ring parts to rotate around the center at a different rate. This is my idle state on the first layer.
On the second layer I've animated the ring parts to elevate from it's location. To test this I've temporarily chose this as the first state after entry.

Only the first layer worked. I tried additive settings, synchronizing layers, but none of those worked. The synch worked on the state, but didn't actually play the animation clip, which is really weird.
The elevation animation should activate on trigger later, and I don't want the idle rotation to stop or change.

How can I pull this off?

Comment: We are going to need to see some screenshots of your animator to see what is wrong.
If you are only trying to accomplish these simple animations, however, it may be easier and more efficient to rotate and translate your objects in a script instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why not scripting?**

Doing animations from script is slower, esspecially if I want to rotate and scale 8 different objects with different values. Also, the animation curves (which are making the animation smooth) would take quite a lot of time to implement.

**SOLUTION**

So, I figured out the problem. I didn't **set weight** for the animation layers.
**Setting the weight of the second layer to 1 and making it additive** solved the problem.